# How do I query Outlook email with a "No Date" due date?

Tags: email, date, search, filter, outlook

I can query Outlook email due today with `due:today` and this week with `due:this week` or even `due:thisweek`. However, for email with a `No Date`flag, a `due:none` or `Due:"No Date"` doesn't work. I've tried other combinations with no success. What is the correct query to achieve this filter?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Sort of? It's a query you can make inside the Search box in Outlook and I cannot find a way to do this after much Googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a combination of filters in the [Query builder](https://www.google.pt/search?q=outlook%20query%20builder&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=1BwjV_6qM4XyUI2Xq8AM) (but also for conditional formatting View):

- Follow up Flag is not empty
- Due date does not exist

Comment: Thank you for your response! It helped me found the query that I was looking for,

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The query is:

```
due:[]
```